# PHPUnit with Symfony Service

Tags: php, unit-testing, symfony, phpunit

So I'm fairly new to PHPUnit and unit testing, but I want to unit test a service that I wrote.  The service basically finds the entities and updates a property within the entity.  I'm using the EntityManager's persist() and flush() methods to update the database table associated with the entities.

Speaking in general terms, how would I go about unit testing the service without hitting the database?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could (among other things) create a [mock](http://www.phpunit.de/manual/3.0/en/mock-objects.html) database connection and put it on place of your actual connection. In this mock you would check if the queries sent to database are what they're supposed to be.

Comment: I just read up on https://github.com/doctrine/data-fixtures#readme and was wondering if that's the way to go?  Basically insert, update and then remove test data into our dev db through fixtures.  Any thoughts on that approach?

Comment: That works too. Simpler to set up. More difficult to keep the test datasets updated. Slower (it nees to go through DB after all)